# D3 grouped dot matrix with 2 rows each groups

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create some sort of unit graph (I don't actually know the name of it). What I'm trying to achieve is that the circles render next to each other and when they reached a limit (for example 2) they stack on top of each other and so on.

I just don't know how to solve this kind of problem and need some help to throw me the right direction and possible help me with it.

I made a JS fiddle where you can see all the dots stacked on top of each other in each group.

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2xyjf4nu/1/)

Most of the code can be seen there, but I expect something needs to happen here where I need to add something with the CX

```
var dots = groups
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data(d => d3.range(0, d.apples))
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('class', 'dot')
  .attr('r', 10)
  .attr('cy', d => y(d))
  .style('fill', 'blue')
```

For the most part I got it solved but this is the final result I wanna achieve. The outcome needs that dots group them self 2 each row. Here is a picture of the outcome I'm trying to achieve.
 [image: matrix graph 2 rows]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your day=7 example in the image is not matching the requirement

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5Lmjogqh/1/